# Connect WPA2 PSK wifi connection programmatically (react-native-android-wifi)

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

```
I just tried to connect the wifi programmatically using react-native-android-wifi packages. 

Followed by this link [https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-android-wifi][1]    

import wifi from 'react-native-android-wifi';    
wifi.findAndConnect(this.state.ssid, this.state.pass, (found) => {     
      if (found) {
        console.log("Wi-Fi is in range"); //It returns properly in this block but it is not showing my phone
      } else {
        console.log("Wi-Fi is not in range");
      }  
});
```

it returns true also and received output "Wi-Fi is in range" but Wi-Fi is not connected (showing) on my phone.

```
Can you please provide the sample code or advise to me and also How can I connect open Wi-Fi network?.
```